# Is there a way to run the python scripts through Power Automate without Azure?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, selenium, power-automate

I want to automate my python script to run on everyday basis. Is it possible to automate them using Power Automate but without Azure?

I tried with Azure but i wanted to know if there is any way that i can use it without Azure.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what Azure service did you use to create it on Azure?.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, we don't have any connector to run python script.

Generally, If you are using azure then you can make use of [Azure function app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages) with [HTTP trigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function) (to run the python script) and can be integrated in your workflow as well.

As you have mentioned that you don't want to use azure you need to build a custom solution for example, If you have a website which allows custom API, then you can built your python program on the website and can use the custom connector to connect to the website and pass information.

You can pass the input parameters from flow and the processing will be done on the website and it will share back the information will which in turn be processed by flow and displayed to the end user.

Comment: I am also trying to do this. I have a few questions. 1: Are there python package limitations on Azure functions (i.e. is selenium supported). 2: Does an intranet site or SharePoint site fall under the category of a website?. 3. How do I know if my website supports a custom API?. I wish there was a tutorial online on this.

Comment: Thank you so much will try it and update soon.